# d3 line graphic, get data from Object instead of CSV

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to replicate the graphic from here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1166403

the only difference being that instead of getting the data from a csv file I would like to get it from a js Object.

So data like this:

```
symbol,date,price
S&P 500,Jan 2000,1394.46
S&P 500,Feb 2000,1366.42
S&P 500,Mar 2000,1498.58
```

I transformed it into:

```
var data = [{"symbol":"S&P 500","date":"Jul 2002","price":"1.63"},
{"symbol":"S&P 500","date":"Aug 2002","price":"7.63"},
{"symbol":"S&P 500","date":"Sep 2002","price":"7.23"}];
```

And tried mapping the data values to line() like this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(data.map(function(d) { return x(d.date); }))
    .y(data.map(function(d) { return y(d.price); }));
```

But I am still getting path is not a NaN error:

https://jsfiddle.net/buh6dLg9/

`d.date` returns as expected, but I don't understand why it should be
 `x(d.date)`

Many of those examples at bl.ocks.org are using external files and I would like to see how to use data from an object instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the parsing of the data from text to the right format, using function `type` (which in turn calls the date parser function). Just insert the following line:

```
data.forEach(type);
```

About the line axis, you need to revert to the original code (which doesn't have to change for you):

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });
```

`d.date` is your original data, `x(d.date)` translates this into an x-coordinate for the drawing, and the block above tells that the data should use the `x` and `y` functions to generate the coordinates. at this point, the data doesn't have to be taken into account.

https://jsfiddle.net/2d042rnL/

---

I general, to use local data instead of an external file, look for the line as this one:

```
d3.csv("readme.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  ...
}
```

and you need to apply the same preprocessing to your data (here, the `type` function), and then call the function. What I usualy do is the following:

```
process =  function(error, data) {
  ...
}
/* use external file: */
//d3.csv("readme.csv", type, process) 
/* use local data: */
data.forEach(type)
process(false, data)
```